# How can we turn PostgreSQL table's data into a heatmap data?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have table that contain `user_id`, `date` and `time`

```
user_id    date       time
129629  2018-11-01  01:18:50 PM
188747  2018-11-02  02:18:50 PM
261476  2018-11-03  06:18:50 PM
101866  2018-11-04  02:19:36 PM
156421  2018-11-05  06:23:01 PM
190261  2018-11-06  01:23:01 PM
247427  2018-11-07  05:23:01 PM
247579  2018-11-08  03:23:01 PM
170536  2018-11-09  01:23:42 PM
186961  2018-11-10  04:24:51 PM
118408  2018-11-11  01:18:50 PM
900006  2018-11-12  02:18:50 PM
900095  2018-11-13  01:18:50 PM
162458  2018-11-14  02:19:36 PM
100881  2018-11-15  06:23:01 PM
136095  2018-11-16  01:23:01 PM
100881  2018-11-17  05:23:01 PM
900058  2018-11-18  03:23:01 PM
134921  2018-11-19  02:18:50 PM
162873  2018-11-20  01:24:51 PM
```

I want to create visitor heatmap form this particular data like in the sample given below:

```
           sun  mon tue wed thu fri sat
01:00:00 PM 1   0   3   0   1   2   0
02:00:00 PM 1   2   0   1   0   1   0
03:00:00 PM 1   0   0   0   1   0   0
04:00:00 PM 0   0   0   0   0   0   1
05:00:00 PM 0   0   0   1   0   0   1
06:00:00 PM 0   1   0   0   1   0   1
```

So far I am only able to get list of dates in between time range with the help of this query.

```
select date from user_visits where time >='01:00:00' and time <='01:59:59'
```

I am unable to understand how to format data like the given sample.

Comment: This is tagged for mysql and postgresql. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using for this postgreSQL but same table also available in MYSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filtered aggregate is the easiest way to do it:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', time) AS hour,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM date) = 0) AS sun,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM date) = 1) AS mon,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM date) = 2) AS tue,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM date) = 3) AS wed,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM date) = 4) AS thu,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM date) = 5) AS fri,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(dow FROM date) = 6) AS sat 
FROM user_visits GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY hour;

   hour   | sun | mon | tue | wed | thu | fri | sat 
----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 13:00:00 |   1 |   0 |   3 |   0 |   1 |   2 |   0
 14:00:00 |   1 |   2 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   0
 15:00:00 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0
 16:00:00 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1
 17:00:00 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   1
 18:00:00 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1
(6 rows)
```

**Remarks:**

- I assumed that you are using the data types `date` and `time without time zone`.
- It would be better to store a single `timestamp with time zone` instead of two fields.
- The query uses standard SQL, but I don't know if MySQL supports all the features used.

Comment: Sir is there any way that I select a day like "tue" and it show me only that days that are greater than zero ? the result will be like 

   hour   | sun | mon | tue | wed | thu | fri | sat 
----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 13:00:00 |   1 |   0 |   3 |   0 |   1 |   2 |   0

Answer (score 1):

Use the [date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

```
date_part('hour', time) -- gives time rounded to hour
extract(dow from date) -- returns day of week from date
```

The query:

```
select 
    date_part('hour', time) as hour, 
    sum((extract(dow from date) = 0)::int) as sun,
    sum((extract(dow from date) = 1)::int) as mon,
    sum((extract(dow from date) = 2)::int) as tue,
    sum((extract(dow from date) = 3)::int) as wed,
    sum((extract(dow from date) = 4)::int) as thu,
    sum((extract(dow from date) = 5)::int) as fri,
    sum((extract(dow from date) = 6)::int) as sat
from user_visits 
group by hour
order by hour
```

[Test it in rextester.](https://rextester.com/EMWKC60402)